# Should I use a ISBN or DOI?

Tags: publications, books, latex, doi

I will soon end my work on book about a statistical computing environment and its use in my field. It will require the reader to use the electronic copy alongside with the particular software open in his computer. For this reason, there is little incentive to have it printed. The book will be self published, as I am familiar with LaTeX and similar tools.

Digital identifiers are quick and easy to  obtain now-a-days. One can upload the material to Zenodo.org and close its source, thus generating a DOI that will be further indexed by Google Scholar.

- In this scenario does it make any sense in trying to register this material with a ISBN?